# When an app crashes in ios, does it create a core dump anywhere?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gdb, coredump

Are core dumps available for ios apps? I've got some nasty bugs and checking out the runtime state would be pretty helpful.

Comment: I disagree with Alex. The main point of the core dump being to be able to debug your application _after_ it crashed - even if it is just to get the stack trace. And sometimes you just don't want to flood it with logs for each method call. Maybe you don't understand core dumps if you've never used them.

Answer (score 1):

No, I've never heard of core dump's being done on iOS.  Crash logs with stack trace are saved.